# contenteditable div - divide a span tag - avoid nesting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested, contenteditable

I'm working on a typing tool using contenteditable. When the user types some text I insert it in a span tag and add it to the main div; the result is something like this:

```
<span style="color: black;">hello</span>
```

If the user puts the caret inside the word "hello" and starts typing with a different color the result will be:

```
<span style="color: black;">he<span style="color: red;">new text</span>llo</span>
```

What I actually would like to achieve is:

```
<span style="color: black;">he</span>
<span style="color: red;">new text</span>
<span style="color: black;">llo</span>
```

I would like to avoid having nested span elements.
Currently I use this procedure to add the span tag:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

var spanTag = "<span id='newSpan' style='color: " + currentColor + "'>00000</span>"; // &#8203;
var documentFragment = range.createContextualFragment(spanTag);

range.insertNode(documentFragment);

var dummySpan = document.getElementById("newSpan");

range.setStart(dummySpan, 1);
range.setEnd(dummySpan, 1);

sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);

$("#newSpan").removeAttr("id");
dummySpan.innerHTML = "";
```

I'm just wondering if I'm missing some jquery or javascript function that could help to achieve this easily.

Comment: Seriously. Your question isn't clear to me. What are you trying to achieve actually?

Comment: When the user types inside a span tag I add another span tag which is nested within the first one. I don't want this to happen, I just want all the tags to be separated and not nested.

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully now it's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it with this function. Basically I split in half the current tag text at the caret position, create two separate tags each with half of the text, create a new tag with the current color in the middle and put the caret in it.

```
function typeInKanji() {

    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

    var currentNode = sel.anchorNode;   
    var elementNode = getSelectionElement();

    var caretPosition = getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(elementNode);

    if (elementNode.tagName == "SPAN") { 

        if (elementNode.style.color == currentColor) {

            console.log("span of same color, do nothing and keep typing");

        } else {

            console.log("span of a different color, split it");

            var tagText = elementNode.innerText;

            console.log("text: " + tagText + " position: " + caretPosition);

            var firstHalf = tagText.substr(0, caretPosition);
            var secondHalf = tagText.replace(firstHalf, "");

            // remove the old element with all the text
            $(elementNode).remove();

            var firstTag = "<span style='color: " + elementNode.style.color + "'>" + firstHalf + "</span>"
            var secondTag = "<span style='color: " + elementNode.style.color + "'>" + secondHalf + "</span>"
            var middleTag = "<span id='middleTag' style='color: " + currentColor + "'>00</span>"

            var firstFrag = range.createContextualFragment(firstTag);
            var secondFrag = range.createContextualFragment(secondTag);
            var middleFrag = range.createContextualFragment(middleTag);

            range.insertNode(secondFrag);
            range.insertNode(middleFrag);
            range.insertNode(firstFrag);

            var getMiddleTag = document.getElementById("middleTag");

            console.log(getMiddleTag);

            range.setStart(getMiddleTag, 0);
            range.setEnd(getMiddleTag, 0);

            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);

            $("#middleTag").removeAttr("id");
            getMiddleTag.innerHTML = "";

        }


    }　else {

        // if there is not SPAN tag create one
        insertTag("<span id='newSpan' style='color: " + currentColor + "'>00</span>");

        var dummySpan = document.getElementById("newSpan");

        range.setStart(dummySpan, 1);
        range.setEnd(dummySpan, 1);

        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);

        $("#newSpan").removeAttr("id");
        dummySpan.innerHTML = "";

    }

    typeKanjiNow = false;

}
```

And here the other two functions I use:

```
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {

    var caretOffset = 0;
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;

    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {

        sel = win.getSelection();

        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {

            var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;

        }

    } else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {

        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;

    }

    return caretOffset;

}

function insertTag(tag) {

    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

    var currentNode = sel.anchorNode;   

    var documentFragment = range.createContextualFragment(tag);
    range.insertNode(documentFragment);

}
```